# Making a Ubuntu pedrive into a regular pendrive

Tags: installation, live-usb, usb-drive

I have weird question with a simple answer, but I'm to lazy for simple. (That was a joke). I have two desktopss and a 32 gig pendrive with ubuntu 12.04 installed. My old desktop is ancient, I'd planned on giving it away. To make a long story short, I wiped the harddrive of the old pc, and now I want to recover some lost files using Puppy linux and photorec (i think that the name of the software). You need a place to store the recovered files, and the only thing I have available is the pendrive.

Is it possible to copy all the files (everything not just media) to my new desktop. Afterwards, I would use the pendrive as the storage space for the recovered files. Finally, after transferring the recovered files to a new location, I would transfer the 12.04 files back to the pendrive.

I know that was confusing and overall, kind of ridiculous. It would be much easier just to buy a new jump drive or external harddrive, but the closest electronic store is 20 minutes away. Also, I don't want to spend money on something I'm not going to use often.
I know I promised a short story; I apologize.

Thans in advance.

Comment: which operating system are you using?

Answer (score 0):

How well did you wipe this drive?  If you used anything worth its salt (DBAN, the `shred` command), you won't be able to get anything useful back.

If you actually just deleted the partitions, the good news is it's definitely possible.
I would suggest using GPart (or its front-end GParted), which are included in the Ubuntu LiveCD, to [recover the old partitions entirely](http://docs.oseems.com/general/operatingsystem/linux/recover-lost-partition-table).  That way, photorec won't have to snoop through the whole drive - you'll have the whole filesystem back.  In addition to GPart, the guide has a link to another that'd let you use TestDisk or parted to do the same thing.

You can also use GParted to reformat your USB (as long as you aren't currently booting from it), or even shrink the existing partition so you can make a new one for file storage.  You may have to make several trips between computers to get all of your data, but once that's done you can reinstall the LiveCD the same way you installed it before, or return it to its former size, if you wish.